# Does the order of different styles in a rule matter?

Tags: css

I have noticed that when I look at a rule I have written say for example:

```
label { 
font-size: 12px; 
position: absolute; 
padding: 9px;
color: #666;
}
```

In firebug, it translates as:

```
label {
color: #666; 
font-size: 12px; 
padding: 9px;
position: absolute; 
}
```

Basically, reordering the styles. Why?

Is there an 'ultimate' priority I could be putting in my styles to improve load speeds? Ie is there a load order I'm unaware of?

Comment: You probably should reword your question to say non-duplicated styles within the same selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of styles in your rule does not matter. Firebug seems to sort alphabetically in your case (it may be incidental).

Of course the order will do play role in this, problematic, case:

```
.foo {
    background: url(foo.png) top left repeat-x;
    background-image: url(bar.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order matters:

```
label { 
font-size: 12px; 
position: absolute; 
padding: 9px;
color: #666;
font-size: 15px; 
}
```

The font-size (15px) will overrule the 12px

Comment: Except nothing is being redeclared or overridden in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general: Yes, order does matter in terms of what properties will actually be set.

You can Google for many links on CSS precedence, for example:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

But as far as what you see in the debugger - that's not at all significant for how the CSS will actually be rendered. The order of "color", "font-size", "padding" and "position" in this particular class are simply an artifact of Firebug.

Comment: I understand cascading... I'm talking about the order within the class.

Comment: The order you list "CSS declarations" (e.g. "font-size: 12px") within an HTML class or a CSS rule does *not* matter ... unless the declarations conflict with each other.  In which case it *would* matter, and the second declaration wins.  But again: in general, order CAN matter.  And again, in this case it simply appears to be a benign artifact (and/or "helpful feature") of the Firebug debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the others stated before, the order is important in letting the browser choose, which rule to use, but in order of performance I haven't heard of something like this. As CSS is just a text file the downloading speed will not be affected. BUt I don't think anyone has examined this topic with some test cases.